# What does val = val==0?0:1; mean?

Tags: java

Normally, I usually see `i++;` or `++i;`. However, this is my first time to see something like this:

```
val = val == 0 ? 0 : 1;
```

What does it mean?

Comment: FYI you should never write code like this.

Comment: @bhspencer It depends. If the variables and methods are properly named and the line is short and understandable, it is a good choice.

Comment: In addition to the already correct answers, I find it as being overkill to do `val = val == 0 ? 0 : 1;` , instead simply do `if(val != 0) val = 1;`

Answer (score 3):

The code `val = val==0?0:1;` is a shorter representation of this code:

```
if (val==0)
{
    val = 0;
}
else
{
    val = 1;
}
```

The syntax of `a?b:c` is:

```
<condition> ? <result if true> : <result if false>
```

Answer (score 2):

It means `if val == 0 then set val to 0 else set val to 1`

Comment: please only format code as code

Comment: I just typed it in, the site added `` when it saw the if -> talk to SO if you don't like the formatting

Comment: No need to get grumpy

Answer (score 2):

It is using the *ternary conditional operator*, which looks like

`condition ? [value if true] : [value if false]`.

In this case, it is saying that if `val == 0`, then set `val` to `0`; otherwise, set `val` to `1`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This is the so-called ternary operator, which can be viewed as an "immediate if" expression, that is to say:

```
val = val == 0 ? 0 : 1;
```

amounts to:

```
if (val == 0) {
    val = 0;
} else {
    val = 1;
}
```